# Valid ranges for web site ports in IIS

Tags: windows, iis, http, https, port

In IIS for Windows, you can specify a port for a web site under "Edit Bindings".  80 is the default port and 443 is for a secure protocol.  I'd like to get a complete list of valid port ranges that can be used by a website?  And if a port is allowed, what tells me if the port is available for use on that machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valid ports for such use are 1-65535.  In general, you should use standard ports for your services because this maximizes ease of operation and use.

`netstat -nq` on Windows and `netstat -nvl` on linux (feel free to tweak the options to your liking; all you really need is the list of in-use and particularly listening ports) will tell you which ports are open, but in general you should select a port you know is not used by another application you are running (and you should not have to determine this dynamically).

Comment: Looks like the "q" parameter isn't available on Windows 7

Comment: standard ports list ?

Comment: The standard ports would be 80 and 443.  Others are entirely arbitrary, but should be below 32768.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port